# After registry of both the consumer and prosumer properly, when I try to do the transaction, the transaction is reverted

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, p2p, trading

[image: The error message is like this:]

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:GPL-3.0

pragma solidity 0.8.13;

contract trade{

    constructor() { owner = msg. sender; }

    address owner;

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;

    }


//////////////////////
/////required mappings
    // map consumer address to consumer userID

    mapping(address => uint32) public consumers;

    //map producer address to producerID "is a registered producer"
 
    mapping(address => uint) public producers;

    //map address to energy balance of the users"
 
    mapping(address => uint) public userEnergyBal;

///////////////////////////
//////consumer regster part

    modifier onlyRegisteredConsumers {
        require (consumers[msg. sender] > 0);
    _;
    }
    function registerConsumer (address aconsumer, uint32 auserID, uint buserEnergyBal) onlyOwner external {
        consumers [aconsumer] = auserID;
        userEnergyBal [aconsumer] = buserEnergyBal;

    }

////////////////////////////
//////producer register part

    modifier onlyRegisteredProducers {
    require (producers[msg. sender]>0);
    _;
    }
    function registerProducer(address bproducer,uint buserID, uint buserEnergyBal) onlyOwner external {
    require(buserID>0);
    producers [bproducer] = buserID;
    userEnergyBal [bproducer] = buserEnergyBal;
    }

////////////////////
////////trading part

    function buy_energy (address aproducer, uint64 aenergy) onlyRegisteredConsumers external payable {
    sendEthUser(aproducer);
    }

    function sendEthUser(address _user) public payable{
       payable(_user).transfer(2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're sending 0 eth with your transaction, and your transaction is trying to send 2 wei to `user`, does your contract hold those 2 wei initially? If not, that's the reason why it's not working.

Comment: The balance will be transferred from the account that calls the buy_energy() and eventually the sendEthUser(). So why do I need any balance in my contract? @Foxxxey

Comment: But you didn't send the 2 wei required. You can see that the value sent is 0 wei.

Comment: You need to explicitely send those with the transaction, they arent taken automatically from the users wallet.

Comment: Well, I don't get it clear. How do I need to modify the buy_energy() function? Can you help me with the proper code that I need to add or modify? @Foxxxey

Comment: Well, I don't get it clear. How do I need to modify the buy_energy() function? Can you help me with the proper code that I need to add or modify?  @Nal Luksik

Comment: You don't need to change the contract, you just need to send the 2 wei with the function call.

Comment: In remix, you'd do that using the `value` field in the "deploy  and run transactions" tab. (can't wait for you to realize you're transferring 0.000000000000000002 ETH, and not 2 as you're probably trying to)

Comment: It does not work either. Gives the same error. Even if I set value to 2 wei and transact. @Nal Luksic

Comment: It does not work either. Gives the same error. Even if I set value to 2 wei and transact. @Foxxxey

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong, i tried to reproduce and it works. Did you first call registerConsumer()?

Comment: (also, you can mention more than 1 person in a comment, you don't need to send the same message twice every time, lmao)

Comment: Yes, I did registered both consumer, producer then tried to transact each time. @Foxxxey